# Rails 3 Subdomain with Nginx and Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have a rails app which is deployed over Capistrano to a VPS with a very similar setup to [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps). I have both mydomain.co.uk and admin.mydomain.co.uk. The subdomains work fine locally using lvh.me and the standard Webbrick server, but in production admin.mydomain.co.uk shows exactly the same content as mydomain.co.uk.

**My routes.rb file:**

```
class AdminDomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    puts "Sub = #{request.subdomain}"
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == "admin"
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints(AdminDomain) do
    scope :module => "admin" do
      match '', to: 'admin#index'

      resources :users
    end
  end

  # All the mydomain.co.uk routes...
```

**My Nginx config:**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.<%= application %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  root <%= current_path %>/public;

  server_name mydomain.co.uk admin.mydomain.co.uk;

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /home/deployer/mydomain_combined.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/deployer/mydomain.key;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    expires    max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }

  error_page 503 @maintenance;

  location @maintenance {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The only idea I have is that Nginx is not passing on the request url to the unicorn. I had a similar issue with SSL but solved that by adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`. How can I get the subdomains to function correctly in a production environment under Nginx and Unicorn?

Comment: I also had this problem and I post about it. Here's a answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134046/multiple-rails-4-app-using-nginx-unicorn/18161635#18161635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that under my setup in production `request.subdomain` was set to 'admin.mydomain' whereas in development it was just 'admin'.

Therefore adding this into the routes.rb with a regex works both locally and on my production server:

```
constraints :subdomain => /admin.*/ do
  scope :module => "admin" do
    root to: 'admin#index'
  end
end
```

Comment: You needed to change the `:tld_length` parameter as your live server is deeper than your test one (.co.uk vs .me)