# Trouble with Multiple Rails app routing on Facebook omniauth login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, omniauth

I'm currently maitaining a Rails project that needs to switch its Passenger Rack Middleware to Unicorn. I've bumped into an issue that Unicorn does not seem support subdomain that much, so I have a workaround like the below.

```
require_relative '../lib/route_scoper'

MyProject::Application.routes.draw do
  scope RouteScoper.root do
    get "pages/welcome"

    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

    devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }

    root to: "pages#welcome"

    resources :categories, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :counties, only: [:index], defaults: { format: :json }
    resources :products, only: [:show] do
      resources :votes, only: [:create]
    end

    resources :tickets, only: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

I've made a workaround according to the article here

[Multiple Rails 4 app using nginx + unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134046/multiple-rails-4-app-using-nginx-unicorn)

Everything works fine except our Facebook Login seems to have a routing problem.

```
Started GET "/my_project"
Processing by Devise::CasSessionsController#service as HTML
Redirected to http://events.staging.mainsite/users/auth/facebook
Filter chain halted as :sync_fb_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 49.8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The Rails project is under a domain name like
`http://events.staging.mainsite/my_project`

It always redirect me to `http://events.staging.mainsite/users/auth/facebook` page and show error message 404 not found.

It's used to route at the URL like the below from the old version

```
Redirected to /my_project/users/auth/facebook
```

Not sure if I can overwrite the omniauth path to fix this or simply modify the `route.rb` to point to the right login path, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just figured this out, I have to add a path for my devise
then move it outside the RouteScoper.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }, path: "#{RouteScoper.root}/users"
```